# Visual Studio 2015 does not start, missing .Net Framework 4.6

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I created a virtual machine with Hyper-V and installed Windows 10 Technical Preview on it, due to necessity I had to install Visual Studio 2015 RTM with all features. No sooner said than done! After the setup process, I restarted, as usual, the machine and wanted to start Visual Studio, but it didn't work, telling me:

".Net Framework 4.6 is missing, please install or repair"

I checked the installation. .Net Framework 4.6 is already installed. I also downloaded the .Net Framework 4.6 Preview and Visual Studio .Net Framework 4.6 Installers (Offline+Web) but all telling me it is already installed.

Does anyone have a clue, how I can solve this?

Comment: Use the Visual Studio RTM version instead.

Comment: I am currently installing it.

Comment: could not downgrade, have to reinstall win10

Comment: i am sorry, but i forgot to tell you, i installed RTM, and now i wanted to go back to RC

Comment: If you've upgraded to 10240 that's not going to be possible, as far as I can tell it ships with 4.6final. Why would you?

Comment: @jessehouwing I want to find out if universal WinRT Apps disconnect the connections when they are started in desktop mode in Windows 10 and the user minimizes them, so that the app goes in background.

Comment: And why would you need the RC framework for that?

Comment: @jessehouwing I need to build a Windows 10 app, and I think this only works with Windows 10 SDK on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013 and upwards.

Comment: @jessehouwing, I have 9926 (win10tp)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the [offline installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48137) of .NET 4.6 instead of the web installer. I faced the same issue, and now it's somehow gone. Here's what I did:

- used the offline installer
- "repaired" both .NET 4.6 and VS (several times)
- rebooted after each repairing

Comment: ok I will give this a try, will take me about 4 hours or more, but at the moment i am facing a postgreSQL logging error http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109265/postgresql-bug-logging-with-a-minimum-log-level

Comment: are u using visual studio 2015 RTM or RC version?

Comment: I can't use the Offline Installer, it is not for Windows 10, see: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 (Offline Installer) for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 SP2 Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Wait a second there are two offline-installers: NDP46-KB3033091-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU and NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU, UPDATE: Doesn't work either. UPDATE: tested it in compatibility mode, says it is not working in that mode!

Comment: I'm using RTM on Windows 7. Although everything seems to work, I've just found out SQL Server Management Studio 2014 doesn't start any more after all these operations. I thought Windows 10 includes .NET 4.6...

Comment: maybe thats the problem , that there is a kind of .net 4.6 in the realease windows 10, but this is missing in the technical preview

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message with Windows 8 and I could fix it by reinstalling the .Net framework from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48130 again.

Comment: the issue is the installer is blocked for windows 10, it says that the installer can only be used on older systems than windows 10

Comment: This has solved the problem on my computer running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622450.aspx, uninstall, restart, reinstall, and then restart again.

Comment: Microsoft released your article on November 30, 2015 ... I wrote this question on July 23, 2015. Thanks, I can not evaluate it anymore, I installed Windows 8.1 now.

Comment: So you solved the problem by switching to Windows 8.1?

Comment: I did not solve it, because I can not develop Universal Apps for Windows 10. I started by developing an application for Windows 8.1.