# There is no framework available when attempting to create a new project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and I am attempting to create a new project.  This requires me to select a framework but when I open the framework drop down there are none available.  After doing some research, I should have .Net 4.6 available (I checked, it is installed), but it is not.  I have searched the internet and not found any answers and uninstalling then installing MVS and .Net did not help.  Any advice/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check the installed .NET Frameworks is to use `regedit` and look in the `Windows registry`.

After my installation of VS 2015 Community, I get the following:

[image]

.NET 4.6 is properly included.

---

The new .NET Framework 4.6 also appears under Windows Control Panel / Programs

[image]

---

Finally, you could also look for directory:

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I was able to find 4.6 using regedit and programs but I was unable to find it by searching for the directory you provided.  There isn't a folder called Framework.NETFramework in %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft however there is a Framework folder but it does not have v4.6 in it.
Still unable to use it in visual studio.

Comment: Have you checked this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586403/visual-studio-2015-does-not-start-missing-net-framework-4-6?rq=1)?