# Cannot select .NET framework Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-framework-version

Since installing Visual Studio 2015 I have been unable to select a .NET framework when creating a Visual Studio 2015 project, which means that I cannot create a project. I have seen several posts stating the same issue, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617750/there-is-no-framework-available-when-attempting-to-create-a-new-project-in-visua), but despite having all of these solutions in my environment, I still see this in my IDE:

[image]

Is there a way to link My installed .NET framework to my VS2015 IDE through the IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot select Target Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279515/cannot-select-target-framework-4-5-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: [repair VisualStudio via control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42279515/1466046) this will fix the issue

Comment: When I repair the IDE it hangs when the process reaches "Windows 8.0 Emulation Host"

Comment: is Hyper-V running?

Comment: Yes it's running

Comment: can you run setup and uncheck the Win(Phone)8.x development options?

Comment: Not sure if I did it correctly but I unchecked values related to Windows Emulators. Modifying was OK but when I repaired VS it became stuck at the same place again. When I cancel the operation it just stays stuck at "stopping the current session".  I saw a question (can't remember the link) that talked about making changes in the Registry Editor for VS2015. When I go in there the currentOperation is set to 'repair', probably because the processed wasn't completed. What other values are there? I'm wondering if that's part of the issue.

Comment: I have no idea. ask in [Microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=vssetup)